# Is there a way in tkinter to add multiple keys to a function?

Tags: python, tkinter

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.tk()
def func(key):
   if key == 'a':
      *run code*
   elif key == 'b':
      *run different code* 

root.bind('a','b',func)
root.mainloop()
```

Basically, if the user hits 'a', something different happens than when they hit 'b'. I know how to do this with two functions, but is there any way to only use one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achive this by binding `'<Key>'` which is equivalent to any key. Tkinter provides an [eventhandler](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/bind.htm) that parse the object *event* in that object are [various information](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/event.htm) like [keysym](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm) contained you can use.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
def func(event):
    key = event.keysym
    if key == 'a':
        print('a')
    elif key == 'b':
        print('b') 

root.bind('<Key>',func)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @JarodL Are you asking for curser buttons or button widgets ? For curser button use `event.num`

Comment: I was asking about widgets, but thank you for showing me how to use curser button as well. But, can this work on button widgets?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you asking for. Could you open up a new question with an exampel and post the link to that here ?

Comment: I have to wait 2 days to ask again. Basically, I am asking if a user clicks on the button the first time, one thing happens, but when they click on it again, something else happens (similar to the restore window on a browser)

Comment: Yes I have written some code simliar to this and there are several ways to achive this. I guess the binding isn't the best way to go there but you could use `event.widget` to find out which widget and write some code for this behaviour.

Comment: TYSM, this helps me out a ton.